# php return mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

How is it possible to retrieve the mysql_query from a function? For instance:

```
class A() {
   ...
   function getAll($l=1) {
      ...
      $result = mysql_query($query); 
      return $result
   }
   ...
}

$a = new A();
$r = $a -> getAll(2);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
   // do something
}
```

This code above does not work when I return $result from the function. However, when I use the mysql_fetch_assoc function in getAll function, it works perfectly. So basically, my question is how to return a mysql result set from a function?

** EDIT **

I actually get no errors. The while statement used liked above will just not execute. But the query works perfectly when I execute it from within the getAll function.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get some kind of error? No rows returned?

Comment: Do you get an error?  Do you need a `;` after `return $result;` ?

Comment: Change your `mysql_query` line to this and see if it is just erroring out:  `$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error());`

Comment: Have you tried to print out $result before returnig and $r after function call? (by print_r() function)

Comment: You're not checking if mysql_query was successful. If $result is FALSE, then you should read mysql_error().

Comment: Maybe your db connection is being closed by a destructor somewhere, when a local variable goes out of scope. Maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't return the result resource from the query, but rather return the data extracted from that resource:

```
$data = array();

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

return $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely it works.**

Do a `var_dump($r)` to make sure you're getting a resource. If not, double-check your SQL. There may be an error in it.

Also turn on other error reporting at the top of your script (as well as checking `mysql_error`) for better clues as to what's wrong:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You've edited much of your code so it's difficult to investigate further. **Just make sure that your method is not closing the mysql connection.**